# Get arrowheads to show with nodes in small tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I've got the following code for a tikz diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/01/01]
\ProvidesPackage{freetikz}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main,foreground,background}

\def\thickness{0.7pt}

\tikzstyle{dot}=[circle, draw=black, fill=black!25, inner sep=.4ex, line width=\thickness, node on layer=foreground]
\tikzstyle{blackdot}=[dot, fill=black!50]
\tikzstyle{blackdot}=[dot, fill=gray!40!white]
\tikzstyle{whitedot}=[dot, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{reddot}=[dot, fill=red]
\tikzstyle{greendot}=[dot, fill=green]

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \gdef\node@@on@layer{%
  \setbox\tikz@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\pgfonlayer{#1}\unhbox\tikz@tempbox\endpgfonlayer\egroup}
\aftergroup\node@on@layer
  },
  /tikz/end node on layer/.code={
    \endpgfonlayer\endgroup\endgroup
  }
}
\def\node@on@layer{\aftergroup\node@@on@layer}
\makeatother

% Lengths
\newlength\morphismheight
\setlength\morphismheight{0.6cm}
\newlength\minimummorphismwidth
\setlength\minimummorphismwidth{0.6cm}
\newlength\stateheight
\setlength\stateheight{0.6cm}
\newlength\minimumstatewidth
\setlength\minimumstatewidth{0.89cm}
\newlength\connectheight
\setlength\connectheight{0.5cm}
\tikzset{width/.initial=\minimummorphismwidth}

% Keys
\newif\ifwedge\pgfkeys{/tikz/wedge/.is if=wedge}
\tikzset{wedge}
\newif\ifvflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/vflip/.is if=vflip}
\newif\ifhflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/hflip/.is if=hflip}
\newif\ifhvflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/hvflip/.is if=hvflip}
\newif\ifconnectnw\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw/.is if=connectnw}
\newif\ifconnectne\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne/.is if=connectne}
\newif\ifconnectsw\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw/.is if=connectsw}
\newif\ifconnectse\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se/.is if=connectse}
\newif\ifconnectn\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n/.is if=connectn}
\newif\ifconnects\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s/.is if=connects}
\newif\ifconnectnwf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw >/.is if=connectnwf}
\newif\ifconnectnef\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne >/.is if=connectnef}
\newif\ifconnectswf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw >/.is if=connectswf}
\newif\ifconnectsef\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se >/.is if=connectsef}
\newif\ifconnectnf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n >/.is if=connectnf}
\newif\ifconnectsf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s >/.is if=connectsf}
\newif\ifconnectnwr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw </.is if=connectnwr}
\newif\ifconnectner\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne </.is if=connectner}
\newif\ifconnectswr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw </.is if=connectswr}
\newif\ifconnectser\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se </.is if=connectser}
\newif\ifconnectnr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n </.is if=connectnr}
\newif\ifconnectsr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s </.is if=connectsr}
\tikzset{keylengthnw/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthn/.initial =\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthne/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthsw/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengths/.initial =\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthse/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{connect nw length/.style={connect nw=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n length/.style ={connect n =true, keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne length/.style={connect ne=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw length/.style={connect sw=true, keylengthsw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s length/.style ={connect s =true, keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se length/.style={connect se=true, keylengthse={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect nw < length/.style={connect nw <=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n < length/.style ={connect n <=true,  keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne < length/.style={connect ne <=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw < length/.style={connect sw <=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s < length/.style ={connect s <=true,  keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se < length/.style={connect se <=true, keylengthse={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect nw > length/.style={connect nw >=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n > length/.style ={connect n >=true,  keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne > length/.style={connect ne >=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw > length/.style={connect sw >=true, keylengthsw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s > length/.style ={connect s >=true,  keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se > length/.style={connect se >=true, keylengthse={#1}}}

% Shapes
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{morphism}
{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \anchorborder{\centerpoint}
    \saveddimen\savedlengthnw
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthnw}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthn
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthn}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthne
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthne}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthsw
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthsw}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengths
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengths}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthse
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthse}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\overallwidth
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/width}{\minwidth}
        \pgf@x=\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \ifdim\pgf@x<\minwidth
            \pgf@x=\minwidth
        \fi
    }
    \savedanchor{\upperrightcorner}
    {
        \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance\pgf@y by -.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{north}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{north east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \divide \pgf@x by 2
        \advance \pgf@x by 5pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \divide \pgf@x by 2
        \advance \pgf@x by -5pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{north west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{connect nw}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthnw
    }
    \anchor{connect ne}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthne
    }
    \anchor{connect sw}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengthsw
    }
    \anchor{connect se}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengthse
    }
    \anchor{connect n}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthn
    }
    \anchor{connect s}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengths
    }
    \anchor{south east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{south west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{south}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{text}
    {
        \upperrightcorner
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \backgroundpath
    {
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\thickness}
        \begin{scope}
                \ifhflip
                    \pgftransformyscale{-1}
                \fi
                \ifvflip
                    \pgftransformxscale{-1}
                \fi
                \ifhvflip
                    \pgftransformxscale{-1}
                    \pgftransformyscale{-1}
                \fi
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                    {-0.5*\overallwidth-5pt}
                    {0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {0.5*\overallwidth+5pt}
                    {0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \ifwedge
                    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                        {0.5*\overallwidth + 15pt}
                        {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \else
                    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                        {0.5*\overallwidth + 5pt}
                        {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \fi
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {-0.5*\overallwidth-5pt}
                    {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \pgfpathclose
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \end{scope}
        \ifconnectnw
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectne
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectsw
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectse
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectn
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnects
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectnwf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw);
        \fi
        \ifconnectnef
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne);
        \fi
        \ifconnectswf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectsef
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectnf
        \draw [forward arrow style] (0,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (0,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn);
    \fi
    \ifconnectsf
        \draw [forward arrow style] (0,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths)
            to (0,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectnwr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw);
    \fi
    \ifconnectner
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne);
    \fi
    \ifconnectswr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw)
            to (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectser
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse)
            to (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectnr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (0,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn);
    \fi
    \ifconnectsr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths)
            to (0,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [whitedot] (d0) at (2/2, 4/2) {$\alpha$};
\node [whitedot] (d1) at (1/2, 2/2) {$\beta$};
\node [whitedot] (d2) at (3/2, 2/2) {$\gamma$};
\node [whitedot] (d3) at (0,6/2) {$a$};
\node [whitedot] (d4) at (4/2,6/2) {$b$};
\node [whitedot] (d5) at (0,0) {$c$};
\node [whitedot] (d6) at (2/2,0) {$d$};
\node [whitedot] (d7) at (4/2,0) {$e$};
\draw [->] (d0.center) to[out=180, in=-90] (0,6/2);
\draw [->] (d0.center) to[out=0, in=-90] (4/2, 6/2);
\draw [->] (d0.center) to[out=-90, in=0] (d1.center);
\draw (d0.center) to[out=-90, in=180] (d2.center);
\draw (d1.center) to[out=180, in=90] (0, 0);
\draw (d1.center) to[out=0, in=90] (2/2,0);
\draw (d2.center) to[out=180, in=90] (2/2, 0);
\draw (d2.center) to[out=0, in=90] (4/2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Which looks nice, except that the arrowheads are blocked out by the nodes. Is there any way to get the arrowheads to point to the outside of the nodes?

Comment: Use the node names rather than the coordinates in your `\draw` commands, so instead of `(0,6/2)` use `(d3)`.

Comment: @erik Excellent, thank you. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP claim that his problem is solved by comment.

Comment: @Zarko Wouldn't the appropriate course of action be to convert the comment to an answer and accept it, so anyone with this problem in the future has the question/answer in an easily accessible format?

Comment: @Zarko Also, downvoting because I didn't accept your overly cumbersome code as a solution seems... overly invested. Have a good day.

Comment: You receive answer which solve your problem, however, you claim, that your problem is solved by comment.

Comment: @Zarko I gave you an upvote and thanked you, but your solution would be a nightmare for me to implement; i have tens/hundreds of similar diagrams I need to draw, and can't afford to write that much code for each one. Investing in a longer preamble pays dividends.

Comment: @ Alec Rhea Small answers are often posted as comments and not as answers. In that case it is also state of the art here to mark the question as solved and close it. So Zarkos behaviour is neither against you nor erik.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect, that you after the following image:

[image]

I can be drawn by far, far ...shorter and simpler code as you provide in your question:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 16mm and 8mm, on grid,
     V/.style = {circle, minimum size=7mm, draw, semithick},
every edge/.append style = {draw, - Stealth} 
                        ] 
     \begin{scope}[nodes=V]
\node (v0)    {$\alpha$};
\node (v1)  [below  left=of v0] {$\beta$};
\node (v2)  [below right=of v0] {$\gamma$};
\node (v3)  [below  left=of v1] {$c$};
\node (v4)  [below right=of v1] {$d$};
\node (v5)  [below right=of v2] {$e$};
%
\node (v6)  [above  left=16mm and 16mm of v0]   {$a$};
\node (v7)  [above right=16mm and 16mm of v0]   {$b$};
    \end{scope}
%   edges
\path   (v0) edge[out=180, in=-90] (v6)
        (v0) edge[out=0,   in=-90] (v7) 
%
        (v0) edge[out=-90, in= 30] (v1)
        (v0) edge[out=-90, in=150] (v2)
%
        (v1) edge[out=210, in= 90] (v3) 
        (v1) edge[out=330, in= 90] (v4)
%
        (v2) edge[out=210, in= 90] (v4)
        (v2) edge[out=330, in= 90] (v5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I wonder, what is intention of your huge preamble? It may be that I miss your problem.

Comment: It's just a preamble I copied for general mathematics formatting, I didn't write it, but it does seem to allow for more concise code once I'm in the document -- for example, just modifying my code as erik suggests in the comments yields the desired effect. In any event, thank you for the answer.